# How can I mock position on Huawei with HMS

Tags: react-native, geolocation, location, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-location-kit

I'm trying to use `Geofence` module of Location Kit from HMSCore SDK in `React Native`, since it seems it's not working I wanted to test it by mocking the location. Following the docs I went to `Developer Options > Select mock location app`, but it doesn't let me select my application. Is there another way to do it? Any guide to understand how location services work in general for `React Native`? Docs are not very clear to me and I couldn't find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to apply for the mock location permission in the **AndroidManifest.xml** file.

```
<uses-permission
android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
tools:ignore="MockLocation,ProtectedPermissions" />
```

For more details, you could refer to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/location-develop-steps-0000001050746143#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001050746143__section97010574342).